# What SQL statement will return rows with a matched date and datetimes?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

**Edit: I've been staring at the screen too long and realized that I actually put down 6 o'clock (18) down instead of 4 o'clock (16) like I needed.  I had one row that matched the 18, which is why there was only one row that kept getting returned.  Technically, my code works if I changed it to 16's, but @Gordon Linoff's answer is much faster with the JOINs.  My statement takes 0.33 seconds to return, and Gordon's takes  0.0003.**

I've got three tables that I'm trying to match up rows by two datetime columns and a date column.  My current SQL command looks like:

```
SELECT puyforecast.timestamp, tacforecast.timestamp, date
FROM puyforecast, tacforecast, stnrain
WHERE puyforecast.timestamp LIKE CONCAT(date, ' 18:%')
AND tacforecast.timestamp LIKE CONCAT(date, ' 18:%');
```

This pulls up only the first matching row:
`2013-01-28 18:37:33,   2013-01-28 18:37:34,    2013-01-28`  which is what I would expect from the statement.  I want to see **all** rows that have a matching `date` and `datetime` stamps.  The two timestamps from both `puyforecast` and `tacforecast` should only be the rows where the time is at at 18:00 (4 o'clock in the afternoon).  I don't care about minutes or seconds when comparing the `datetimes`, so those shouldn't have an effect on the matching.

I should be seeing an entry like so:

```
2013-01-28 18:37:33,    2013-01-28 18:37:34,    2013-01-28
2013-01-29 18:00:02,    2013-01-29 18:00:34,    2013-01-29
2013-01-30 18:00:02,    2013-01-30 18:00:34,    2013-01-30
...
```

and &c, with date matching going on until the current date.  The two `datetime` columns go back farther in time than the `date` column does.

I've been trying a few searches, but I can't seem to find what it is I'm searching for.

Comment: You should be trying to do this via a proper join (the syntax has been around since 1996!)

Comment: @Bohemian Now I _really_ look like a SQL newbie. :)  I posted another SQL question on SO, and the triumphant answer was JOIN.  I suppose that's where I can start a search on again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just match these on date?

```
SELECT pf.timestamp, tf.timestamp, date
FROM stnrain s join
     puyforecast pf
     on date(pf.timestamp) = s.date and
        hour(pf.timestamp) = 18 join
     tacforecast tf
     on date(tf.timestamp) = s.date and
        hour(tf.timestamp) = 18
```

Comment: That statement brought up the same first result that I had with my original SQL statement.

Comment: I must have been staring at the screen too long, because I wrote "4 o'clock in the afternoon" but actually put down 6 o'clock.  I do have one instance where the 6 o'clock would match, hence only one row returned.  I changed your example to 16's instead of 18's, and it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The improvement on performance was not because you converted your queries to use the `JOIN` syntax, it was probably because you got rid of the `LIKE` conditions. Date and datetime columns should not be compared with `LIKE`, that is for string comparisons.

You can also rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT p.timestamp AS p_timestamp,
       t.timestamp AS t_timestamp, 
       s.date
FROM stnrain AS s
  JOIN puyforecast AS p
    ON  p.timestamp >= s.date + INTERVAL 18 HOUR 
    AND p.timestamp <  s.date + INTERVAL 19 HOUR
  JOIN tacforecast AS t
    ON  t.timestamp >= s.date + INTERVAL 18 HOUR 
    AND t.timestamp <  s.date + INTERVAL 19 HOUR ;
```

This may use different indexes (on the `timestamp` columns) and it might be more efficient. Of course it might be worse, test it!

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I'll try it out tomorrow when I'm back on the server with the db.

Comment: Interesting.  Your query is just slightly slower than my original by 0.4 seconds.  Do you think it is because of the AND lines?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the `timestamp` columns? How big are the tables?

Comment: The two forecast tables with the `timestamp` columns are small at the moment - 58 rows each, but they grow every day by a few more rows.  I do have indexes on the `timestamp` columns on both tables.

Comment: Add an index on `(date)`, too, if there isn't one. And try testing (all the different versions of the query) with at least a few thousand rows.

Comment: Ah - there is no index on `date`.  I have some old forecast data that I could append to a temporary table to test, but unfortunately I'm stuck waiting for the bulk of the data to come through daily forecast results.